# Change only the symbol \pi of mtpro2, v. lite, with slanted \pi of Mathematical Pi 1 (or similar)

Tags: fonts, pdftex, symbols, mtpro

For example I have this simple MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{newtxtext,amsmath}
\begin{document}
$V=\frac 13 \pi r^2 h;\quad \text{ for } r$
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to replace *only* the symbol `\pi` as the picture below without to use unicode characters?

[image]

NB: This image is taken from the book Modern Physics, For Scientists and Engineers
4th edition, Stephen T. Thornton and Andrew Rex pag. 136.

Comment: here did you get the new pi from?

Comment: From an image on web: google images but I have lost the link. I'm searching the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `π` looks like the ones you would find in fonts sold by [Bitstream](https://www.myfonts.com/foundry/Bitstream/).

> [image: pi] [image: pi2]

Unless you have copies of these commercial fonts, there is no way to change `\pi` into your desired glyph (unless you want to draw one yourself).

By the way, this letterform does not go well with Times at all. I would not recommend changing the already well-designed MathTime Pro.